# Can't handle POST http response html in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, response

I'm trying to show the details of a specific activity. The response in the ngOnInit returns a JSON file correctly after I send a url parameter to the backend.

**activity-details.page.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
//console.log(this.router.snapshot.params.id);
let data = this.activitiesService.getDetails(this.router.snapshot.params)
console.log(this.router.snapshot.params); }
```

This is the service I'm using to communicate with backend. The console.log is showing the response correctly.

**activities.service.ts**

```
activities: Activity;
    
getDetails (data) {
    this.http.post<Activity>(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'activities/getDetails', data, this.httpOptions2).subscribe((data:any) =>  {
      console.log(data.name);
      console.log(data.type_of_activity);
    });
```

The issue is that it's not showing the name in the template.
The console says that the name is undefined.

**activity-details.page.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let activity of activities?.activities'>
<p>Activity name {{ activity.name }} </p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, remember: "your services return Observables, you subscribe in components"

So, your service simply -see the "return"-

```
getDetails (data):Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post<Activity>(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'activities/getDetails',
          data, this.httpOptions2)
}
```

Your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activitiesService.getDetails(this.router.snapshot.params).subscribe((res:any)=>{
     console.log(res)
     this.data=res;
  })
}
```

See that you get the data in subscribe, forget "this.data=this.activitiesService....", you don't get the data equal this.data to the functon.

NOTE: I don't check if your call to the API is ok. e.g. in .NET  in a POST in general you pass and object and your're passing a string, perhafs you need call to `this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'activities/getDetails/'+data,null)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Eliseo. It was very helpful! The name undefined error is not showing anymore, however the template is blank. Do you have an idea what it could be? It may be something wrong in template. The ngFor part in the html shows: <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->

Comment: Thank you anyways. Seems like I didn't need the ngFor in the first place. Thanks again Eliseo!